# Matlab: For loop with window array

Tags: arrays, matlab, math, for-loop, while-loop

This is my one dimensional array A, containing 10 numbers:

```
A = [-8.92100000000000 10.6100000000000 1.33300000000000 ...
     -2.57400000000000 -4.52700000000000 9.63300000000000 ...
     4.26200000000000 16.9580000000000 8.16900000000000 4.75100000000000];
```

I want the loop to go through like this; (calculating mean interval wise) - Interval length of 2,4,8

```
(a(1)+a(2))/2 - value stored in one block of a matrix say m= zeros(10)
then (a(1)+a(2)+a(3)+a(4))/4 ------ mean-----
then (a(1)+a(2)..... a(8))/8
```

Then shift indexes:

```
(a(2)+a(3))/2; - mean
(a(2)+a(3)+a(4)+a(5))/4
(a(2)+a(3)...a(9))/8

SO basically 2^n length interval

 %____ my code _____%
  A= newArrayy;
  sum=0;
  storeD = zeros(3,9);
  flag=true;

  for k=1:9
      n=1;
       while(true)
            if(k+(2^n-1)<10)

               meanSum= mean(A(k):A(k+2^n-1))
               storeD(n,k)= meanSum;

               n=n+1;
               else
        flag=false;
    end
end
```

end

I need to find standard deviation, covariance and mean for each interval, but I get an error on the meanSum line.

Comment: i need to find Standard deviation, Co variance and mean

Comment: You need all these values for each interval? Also what is the error you are getting?

Comment: yea all these value for each interval.

Comment: it shows \busy\ and it computes for a very long time

Comment: You said you get an error at the meanSum line. What error do you get? Or the "error" is it takes too long to run?

Comment: Not sure if that is the problem but in my opinion you should use `2^(n-1)` in the if case as well as the mean argument. Also right now you will never compute the mean of the elements 9,10. Because when k=9 your if case is directly false (9+2-1=10!<10) Same applies for my notation (9+1=10!<10). You have to use less equal 10 as argument i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meanSum line, you should write

```
A(k:k+2^n-1)
```

You want to access the elements ranging from k to k+2^n-1. Therefore you have to provide the range to the selection operation.

A few suggestions:

- Use a search engine or a knowlegde base to gather information on the error message you received.
- Try to understand which operation failed, and how it should work in principle (in your case: the colon operator, e.g. http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html)
- If your own efforts don't lead to success, at least post the error message you get to make the question more clear. Better yet, provide a minimal working example. In your case one or two lines of code would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

```
 A = [-8.92100000000000 10.6100000000000 1.33300000000000 ...
 -2.57400000000000 -4.52700000000000 9.63300000000000 ...
 4.26200000000000 16.9580000000000 8.16900000000000 4.75100000000000];


   sum=0;
   storeD = zeros(3,9);


   for k=1:9
   n=1;
   while(1==1)
   if(k+(2^n-1)<=10)

        meanSum= mean(A(k:k+2^n-1));
        storedD(n,k)= meanSum
        covVar= cov(A(k:k+2^n-1));
        storedC(n,k)= covVar
        stdDev= std(A(k:k+2^n-1));
        storedS(n,k)= stdDev



            n=n+1;
        else
            break;
        end
     end
  end
```

> So this worked :D Thanks for the help! There was an error in while loop as i didn't use a break to exit the loop.